# How to return the first exception that occurred?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, option-type, vavr

There's a method called validate which as input accepts an instance of `Option` and a `Predicate` - two arguments (yeah, I know `Option` should be passed as an argument but this is simplified real-world scenario here. Now, if `Option` is empty I need to throw `NotFoundException`. When it has a value that doesn't match the `Predicate` passed it should fail with `ForbiddenException`. If it has value and it matches the predicate nothing happens.

So this will be:

```
                Option, Predicate
                     /\
          isEmpty() /  \ isDefined()  
                   /    \
            throw NFE    matches(Predicate)
                        / \
                    no /   \ yes 
                      /     \
                throw FE     end
```

I have some solutions but would like potential answerers to come to this question with clear mind ;) My problem is getting the first exception if both tests fail. I expect an elegant solution if I may expect anything ;) All vavr beings allowed (`Either`, `Validation`, `Try`..)

One of the ideas is to use double `Option`:

```
Option
  .of(o.getOrElseThrow(NotFoundException::new))
  .filter(p)
  .getOrElseThrow(ForbiddenException::new);
```

But this seems a bit awkward.

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/47338562) sample project may be found.

Comment: @AxelH: *My problem is getting the first exception if both tests fail* - I always get FE even if it should fail with NFE.

Comment: @AxelH, that was one of ways I tried. If you don't see any problem here - no sarcasm here - provide an answer. I'm really curious to see it!

Comment: I would need to start from scratch ... can't you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: @AxelH, here you go, however my idea was not to provide any example at all.

Comment: You keep saying `Option`, but I think you mean `Optional`.

Comment: @AxelH, it is all written there's a link in the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger tagged this question with `vavr` is not by accident.

Comment: For the one who voted to close the question: actually the code I provided works.

Answer (score 5):

As I see it, the best option would be to create readable code, which in this case means using two `if` statements:

```
if (!o.isPresent()) throw new NotFoundException();
if (!p.test(o.get())) throw new ForbiddenException();
```

Simple, readable and straightforward for whoever will need to maintain this code in the future.

If nonetheless you want to do it in some functional*ish* style:

```
o.orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
o.filter(p).orElseThrow(ForbiddenException::new);
```

With Java 9:

```
o.ifPresentOrElse(
    t -> if (!p.test(t)) throw new ForbiddenException(), 
    () -> throw new NotFoundException());
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of necessity of having readable code in the project.

Comment: I like both solutions for their simple and flat code. This is a good example for the benifits of Optionals not "expiring" after a get operation (get, orElse, orElseThrow, ifPresent...), and can be accessed multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

This would be the solution with `Optional` (don't have the time to check `vavr` but should be close enough)

```
public static <T> void validate( Optional<T> optional, Predicate<T> pred ) throws NotFoundException, ForbiddenException {
    if ( !pred.test( optional.orElseThrow( NotFoundException::new ) ) )
        throw new ForbiddenException();
}
```

Don't know a prettier way to throw that `ForbiddenException` unfortunately.

If you want a full functional solution, you will need an `Optional`

```
Optional.of( 
    pred.test( 
       option.orElseThrow( NotFoundException::new ) 
    ) 
).filter( b -> b ).orElseThrow( ForbiddenException::new );
```

The exception are thrown in the correct order since we only check the `Predicate` after the `option` check.

Comment: Thanks, but using `if` statement that is easy ;)

Comment: @Opal That's the problem when you want to do everything in a "new" feature... you stop think the simple way ;)  What is wrong using a condition on a `boolean`, no `NPE` possible on that predicate result (the point of `Optionnal` is mostly to stop have ` != null` checks). Keep it simple.

Comment: I came to the same result (using `if`) independently. While it's not really functional, there was no reason to strive for a pure functional solution as the requirements themselves are asking for throwing exceptions.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete last solution, using an `Optional<Boolean>`, just to be able to `filter` seems overkill. I prefer the first one ;)

Comment: Yea, I prefer the first one too. I don't consider using `if` an antipattern in functional style or something, especially since we're to throw exceptions.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete, you're absolutely right. Unfortunately this is legacy code with exceptions being thrown here and there, everywhere :/